# How do I get my Monstera deliciosa plant to grow upwards instead of sideways?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, monstera

Most of the leaves on my Monstera plant grow sideways, rather than upwards. What causes this? How do I make the leaves grow vertically?

For context, I've had my Monstera for about a year. I recently moved it from a west-facing window to an east-facing window.

[image: Monster deliciosa plant]

Comment: A comment because I am not confident in what I am saying. 1: make sure light comes from above, not from the sides. 2: trim some side leaves. 3: provide mechanical support for all leaves to climb upwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plant's stems seem quite upright but the plant itself seems slightly droopy. Hard to tell for sure, but if the plant really needs water that would help to raise the leaves a bit.

In general with the long petioles the leaves will most of the time have a curve in them, bending down due to the weight of the leaf itself.
To manage it the most effective way is to stake (with a wooden stake or moss pole) up the plant. Here is an article about that [How To Stake Your Monstera Deliciosa](https://blog.leonandgeorge.com/posts/how-to-stake-monstera).